# Get Ember Data to accept different key pair

Tags: ember.js

My API works almost the way Ember wants it to, with one exception. All my JSON is under the namespace "data". Ember wants it to be under the namespace of the model, like "users". How can I tell ember to just use the "data" key?

Comment: Look at overriding http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_serialize - call `var data = this._super...` and then change the key to "data" instead of modelName

Answer (score 0):

What does your `app/application/adapter.js` file look like? Take a look at the Ember [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_customization) for customizing your endpoints. My guess is that it should look something like this for you:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'data'
});
```

Comment: `namspace` only changes the url. What I need to change is the actual key in the data it's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the initial response payload in adapter's `handleResponse` hook: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_handleResponse

There you can overwrite the root of the payload with the one that Ember Data expects.